# Compilation error "s is undeclared," but it is the result of `scanf`

Tags: c, if-statement, char, scanf

this is my code it is for calculating resistors in series or parallel the error is on line 12

```
if ( sp == s )
```

full code in case of earlier mistake

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ( void ) {
    char sp ;
    float a, b, resistancep, resistances ;
    printf ("Enter s for resistor in series or p for parallel\n") ;
    scanf ( " %c", &sp ) ;
    printf ("Enter two resistors calculate\n" ) ;
    scanf ("%f%f", &a, &b ) ;
    resistancep = a * b / ( a + b ) ;
    resistances = a + b ;
    if ( sp == s ) {
            printf ( "The total resistance is%f\n", resistances ) ;
    }
else {
            printf ( "The total resistance is%f\n", resistancep ) ;
    }
```

I have also tried

```
if ( sp == "s" )
```

and

```
if ( sp, s )
```

Comment: Please edit and tag with the language you're using (I'm guessing C).

Comment: Just curious : what was `if ( sp, s )` supposed to mean ?

Answer (score 4):

You probably want

```
if ( sp == 's' )
```

Just `s` is looking for a *variable* named s, which you haven't declared.

`"s"` usually refers to a *string*, which is an array of characters. You are reading a single character off of input, and `"s" != 's'`. Remember, and array (almost) never equals an element of the array.

Comment: Well, technically, if the cpu architecture and memory layout were just right a string could equal its first character...

Comment: @Kevin, very true (which could become nasty bug if it did). I qualified "never" just to be sure.

Comment: An array is *never* equal to an element of the array, nor is it unequal. `"s"` is of type `char[2]`, which decays to `char*`; `'s'` is of type `int`. `"s" != 's'` is neither true nor false; it's a compile-time error.

Comment: @Kevin: No, a string can't equal its first character; they're of distinct types that cannot be compared.

Comment: @KeithThompson I get a compile time *warning*.

Comment: @Kevin: The C standard requires a "diagnostic". It doesn't require it to be fatal. (If you're using gcc, the `-pedantic-errors` option makes it a fatal error; IMHO that *should* be the default.)